# Microsoft Graph accessing through custom login

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have a standard Microsoft Graph code sample that does the following:

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.AzureADAuthority);            
string redirectUri = Url.Action("EmployeeAuthorize", "Account", null, Request.Url.Scheme);
Uri authUri = authContext.GetAuthorizationRequestURL(SettingsHelper.O365UnifiedResource, SettingsHelper.ClientId, new Uri(redirectUri), UserIdentifier.AnyUser, null);
return Redirect(authUri.ToString());
```

This brings up the Microsoft login page that I have customized as much as I can and goes through Azure AD and I can access the unified graph API either Azure AD or SharePoint, one drive for business etc...

The problem is that executives don't like the login experience at all, even though they love access to office365 via the unified graph api, and I am asking how I can create a custom experience with the following criteria:

1. no tenant requirements - ie. login name can be foo@azure_AD_tenant.com or foo@gmail.com or foo@outlook.com. Currently Azure AD requires a tenant name or "live id" subscription, and I can't have restrictions on the login name as we want clients or even casual guests to access some of our content via shared files through roles.
2. ability to create roles for the login account that can be anything we want like admin, premium client, guest etc...
3. access to the unified graph api...like office 365 shared files or yammer conversations, groups etc...
4. login UI must be 100% customizable - ie. no redirect to a Microsoft login page experience, but our own experience. It is understood this could mean keeping passwords and adding multi-authentication on our own.

Basically 100% custom login experience and a token to access to Graph API.

One possible solution might be:

Scenario:
1. User creates an account through our UI only (foo@outlook.com / mypassword), and we hold that in a database\service fabric. This allows us to create our own roles.
2. Upon account creation, we create an azure AD account (api\powershell) for foo_outlook@tenant.com. This could satisfy the Azure AD Tenant requirement in the login name.
3. When the user logins in again, we access Azure AD with foo_outlook@tenant.com\mypassword. But this requires an API for the graph API where I can use username & password to get a token and I'm not sure this exists?

I also need 3rd party identities, but that feature is not available yet.

But can I at least create my own 100% personal login experience and get a token for access to the graph API?

thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Great to see you making use of Microsoft Graph here.
Rob, you seem to be asking a multitude of questions here, ranging from customizing the sign in experience, having your own sign in experience (which is possible but comes with some limitations), supporting social identity providers, guest users, user roles defined by your application, Microsoft Graph capabilities.  I won't be able to answer all your questions here, but can give you some answers

Azure AD does have some business to business capabilities - you can find out a little more here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wo5J61Hp_Z0 and https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Azure-AD-Identity/AzureADB2B.  This will allow you to invite external users (guests) to share/access your applications.  It support Microsoft Accounts social identities too, but doesn't yet support other identity providers (like FB or Google).

Azure AD does provide some limited tenant branding for the sign in page.  You could use a different flow for OAuth (password flow) where you could build your own login experience to get the username/password and send that to AAD for authentication. But you'll lose a lot by doing this, like MFA, conditional access flows, self-service password reset, and the B2B flows (for inviting a guest and signing them in).

Guest users (that you've invited) are somewhat like regular users, so they can also use apps that use the Microsoft Graph.  Currently Microsoft Graph does not expose Yammer conversations BTW.

There's also a way to define app specific roles (like admin, premium client, etc) that can be assigned to users/guests as part of assigning the application to that user. Dushyant has a nice blog about this here: http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/

HTHs,

Comment: Our problems would be solved if we just had more control over what the login page looks like, and foo@gmail.com would be allowed. For employees it's not a problem, but for clients it must be seamless.

Comment: For example, the redirect login page looks like a Microsoft page, and when the user types in foo@tenant.com the branding comes in and that experience is not seamless. So there needs to be a way to know the tenant on redirect to allow initial branding of the login page at the very least. The B2B is a step in the right direction, but if a "guest" for us could be anybody, it appears we need two login systems.

Comment: Dan, thanks very much for your response. Do you have any comments on an alternative approach where there are 2 login systems. Client username foo@abc.com gets a secondary Azure AD account foo@tenant.com? This would require two api's one for adding the user, and one for getting a graph token using username\password...do these types of API's exist?

Answer (score 0):

Azure B2C and B2P features solves our issues combined with Azure Fabric service. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/active-directory-b2c/

These Azure services are in Preview, but when you combined B2C, B2P and Azure AD, you cover Client, Partner, Employee scenarios. Then when you add Azure Fabric Services, you can create a service that can bridge areas the Graph API might not have available.